# how to display UIProgressView on didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate of UICollectionView in Objective-C ?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiprogressview

I want to display **progress view** in **collection view** when user click on the cell and also want to **display progress** of that cell's progress view.

**//...in .h file i have declared UIProgressView -**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIProgressView *pv;
```

**//...then use it in .m file as -**

I have added **UIProgressView** in **UICollectionView**'s method **cellForItemAtIndexPath** as follows;

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    pv = [[UIProgressView alloc]init];
    pv.frame = CGRectMake(45, 270, 230, 50);
    pv.progress = 0.0f;
    pv.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleDefault;
    pv.hidden = YES;

   [cell.contentView addSubview:pv];

  return cell;

}
```

And then show progress view and its progress in **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** as follows;

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //to show progressview in cell..
            UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSLog(@"subviews - %@",selectedCell.contentView.subviews);
            pv = (UIProgressView *)[selectedCell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
            pv.hidden = NO;

           [self performSelector:@selector(checkDownload) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}


//to check whether all images are downloaded or not and showing progress accordingly
-(void)checkDownload
{
    NSError *error;

    NSArray* arrArticleImages = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    arrArticleImages = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:imgPath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"arr cnt-%d",arrArticleImages.count );

    if (arrArticleImages.count <= 8)
    {
        float m = (float)arrArticleImages.count / 100;
        float t = pv.progress ;
        float g = m + t;

        pv.progress = g;

        NSLog(@"prgs-%f",g);

        [self performSelector:@selector(checkDownload) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
    }
    else
    {
        pv.progress = 1.0;

        [self insertIntoDatabase];

        [self performSelector:@selector(goToNewsPaperView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }

    arrArticleImages = nil;
}
```

But now problem with this is that, i click on one cell it starts showing progressview with progress but as soon as click on another cell in between , the first cell's progress stops showing progress and second progress starts showing progress.

I want to display each cell's progressview's progress if it is clicked.

I think my approach is in wrong way.

I can not be able to find it out.

How can i do this??

Please help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because yout getting new refrence of your progress view at **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**. what about previous refrence of progrress view.

You can add all **progress view** in **NSDictionary** with keyvalue **index path**.
And in **checkDownload** pass your **index path** then get that progress view from **NSDictionary** with passed **index path** and use it

//Initialize you NSMutable dictionary somewhere else
And add progress view either in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            pv = [[UIProgressView alloc]init];

            [dictionary setObject:pv forKey:indexpath];

        }
```

Or you can add progress view in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
         //to show progressview in cell..
             UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

             NSLog(@"subviews - %@",selectedCell.contentView.subviews);
             pv = (UIProgressView *)[selectedCell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
             pv.hidden = NO;
             [dictionary setObject:pv forKey:indexpath];

             [self performSelector:@selector(checkDownload) withObject:indexpath afterDelay:1.0];
        }
```

Customize you checkDownload with

```
  -(void)checkDownload:(NSIndexPath*)indexpath
    {
       pv = [dictionary objectForKey:indexpath];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Exactly i want like this. But i have no idea how to do this. Can you please explain it in brief or provide sample code??

Comment: You can take dictionary as instance variable add progress view to that dictioanty in cellForIndexPath or didSelectItemAtIndexPath method respective of index path

Comment: thanks bro. your answer is the exact solution. but i can not be able to test it. because i am checking image downloading in **-(void)checkDownload:(NSIndexPath*)indexpath** method. and as i clicked in 2nd cell , the path is chenged and pv.progress doesnt work. So need to call this method in queue. how can i do this?

Comment: You can do this with NSOperation. This link may help you  "http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same object `pv` in all cells, you need to do the following:

Create UIProgressView for each cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIProgressView *pv = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
    pv.tag = 10;
    .....
}
```

And in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath get the reference and pass it to the download function:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //to show progressview in cell..
        UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"subviews - %@",selectedCell.contentView.subviews);
        UIProgressView *pv = (UIProgressView *)[selectedCell viewForTag:10]; 

       // pass the progressView to your checkDownload
       [self performSelector:@selector(checkDownload:) withObject:pv afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

and the checkDownload will be:

```
-(void)checkDownload:(UIProgressView *)progressView{
   //use progressView instead of pv
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But than how can i use that progressview in **-(void)checkDownload** method for showing progress ??

Comment: You can tag your pv, `pv.tag = 10;` and access it like `progressView = (UIProgressView *)[yourCell viewForTag:10];`

Comment: But how can i access/use progressview in -(void)checkDownload method ??

Comment: Check the answer, you will pass it as a parameter.